# Windows Metro Application Certification Failing on RTM

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

We created a XAML C# Project on Windows8(RTM ) but it failed to get certified using Windows App Cert Kit
   But this failure occurred on RTM Machine we were able to pass the test on Preview Release.

Just to ensure this might be happening due to RTM we created a Sample Grid Layout Project and checked using the Certification Kit but even this failed .

Please Help...

Comment: Mine passed before and still passes under RTM.  Maybe if you gave some details about what it failed on that would help.

Comment: Could you include the failure messages? They will help pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: It was compiled in Release Mode

Comment: Basically all the tests failed ...
The Failure Results Lists:: 
1.Crashes and hangs test
  - FAILED : App launch tests
  - PASSED : Crashes and hangs
2.App manifest compliance test 
  - FAILED : App manifest
3.Windows security features test (Passed)
4.Supported API test (Failed)
5.Performance test 
  - FAILED : Bytecode generation
  - FAILED : Performance launch
  - FAILED : Performance suspend
6. App manifest resources test(Failed)
7. Debug configuration test(Failed)  
8. File encoding  (Failed)
9. App Capabilities test ...
I tried with a Sample Example but still the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. There are changes between RTM and Release Preview, including version number changes that will automatically trigger a fail in the WACK test tool.

Basically, you need to recompile your project code using RTM Visual Studio on an RTM copy of Windows 8.  you'll want to update any of your references as well if you're using third-party components.